# GIT - config --global user.name

Tags: git, logging, configuration, terminal, config

I am using git on a project and every time I want to commit something in the terminal, I have to enter this line of command:

```
git config --global user.name "myusername"
```

I just changed my computer and I didn't have to do this on my former laptop. Is there a way to skip this stage?

Comment: You should only have to do this once per setup if you set it globally, which it looks like you are. What is the error you get if you do not set it before committing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your global configuration using

```
git config --global -e
```

Add the following section if it does not yet exist:

```
[user]
    name = Your Name
    email = your.email@example.com
```